# Using a Foreach loop seems to prevent footer.php from loading

Tags: loops, foreach, footer

isDot()) continue;
    if (stristr($fileInfo->getFilename(), $familyName)){
    echo "

getFilename()."'>".$fileInfo- 
    >getFilename()."

";
    }
    //  }else{
    //   echo "nope";
    //}
    }
    if (str_contains("Adams-Doc1.png", $familyName)){
    echo "yes"; 
      

?>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks I discovered the last "If" statement was the problem so all is good.